# GitLab showing all changes in my commit. How change this?

Tags: git, gitlab

In Pull Request my commit shows changes to the entire file, not my local ones. As if i changed the whole file. I rebase from mainline and pushed changes.

Tried creating a new branch onto develop - didn't help

Comment: Hard from tell precisely from your wording, but it sounds like a line ending problem. Check your editor's auto-(re)formatting features to ensure you're not unwittingly replacing LF with CRLF or the reverse.

Comment: Post this comment as an answer. This is really true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell precisely from your wording, but it sounds like a line ending problem.

Check your editor's auto-(re)formatting features to ensure you're not unwittingly replacing LF with CRLF or the reverse.

Maybe also take a look at this [good base reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) on the subject, namely chapter "Formatting and whitespace".